# Rails4 hstore issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I have problem with saving array with `hstore`

My migration code

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore'
    enable_extension 'hstore'
    create_table :properties do |t|
...
      t.hstore :image, array: true, default: []
...
    end
```

Issue is when im trying to create record like `x = Property.create(image:['a','b'])`

im getting

```
x.image 
=> [{}, {}]
```

Why it happens?

Comment: You're trying to put an array of strings into an array of hstore. Wouldn't you want to store something more like `image: [{'a' => 'b' }, { 'c' => 'd' }]`?

Comment: @muistooshort  there is no possibility to do like i want?

Comment: You can do it like you want but not with hstore, use array instead. Read more about Rails and Postgresql Array  here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array